# CUDA Address Out of Bounds

Tags: c, cuda, gpu

I have been playing with a simple CUDA program that just zeros out global memory.  Below is the device code as well as the host code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void kernel(float *data, int width) {
    int x = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y;

    if (x > (width-1)) {
        printf("x = %d\n", x);
        printf("blockDim.x = %d\n", blockDim.x);
        printf("blockIdx.x = %d\n", blockIdx.x);
        printf("threadIdx.x = %d\n", threadIdx.x);
    }   

    if (y > (width-1)) {
        printf("y = %d\n", y);
        printf("blockDim.y = %d\n", blockDim.y);
        printf("blockIdx.y = %d\n", blockIdx.y);
        printf("threadIdx.y = %d\n", threadIdx.y);
    }   

    data[y * width + x] = 0.0;
}

int main(void) {
    const int MATRIX_SIZE = 256;
    float *data, *dataGPU;
    int sizeOfMem;
    int x = MATRIX_SIZE;
    int y = MATRIX_SIZE;

    cudaDeviceReset();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    sizeOfMem = sizeof(float) * x * y;

    data = (float *)malloc(sizeOfMem);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dataGPU, sizeOfMem);

    cudaMemcpy(dataGPU, data, sizeOfMem, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //int threads = 256;
    //int blocks = ((x * y) + threads - 1) / threads;

    dim3 threads(16, 16);
    dim3 blocks(x / 16, y / 16);

    kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(dataGPU, MATRIX_SIZE);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();

    cudaMemcpy(data, dataGPU, sizeOfMem, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(dataGPU);

    free(data);

    return 0;
}
```

I continue to receive address out of bounds error messages when running my code with cuda-memcheck.  But this is only if the dimensions of the matrix I have created are 128 or greater.  If I have dimensions that are less than 128, the errors are less frequent (I almost never receive errors).  You may notice that I included print statements in my kernel function.  These statements are only printed when I receive the error messages, because x and y should never be greater than width-1, or in this case 255.  This statement is true, if I have done my math correctly, which I believe I have.  Below is an error message I received from cuda-memcheck:

```
  ========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
  ========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4
  =========     at 0x00000298 in kernel(float*, int)
  =========     by thread (3,10,0) in block (15,1,0)
  =========     Address 0x2300da6bcc is out of bounds
  =========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at kernel launch time
  =========     Host Frame:/usr/lib64/nvidia/libcuda.so.1 (cuLaunchKernel + 0x2c5) [0x472225]
  =========     Host Frame:./test_reg_memory [0x16c41]
  =========     Host Frame:./test_reg_memory [0x31453]
  =========     Host Frame:./test_reg_memory [0x276d]
  =========     Host Frame:./test_reg_memory [0x24f0]
  =========     Host Frame:/lib64/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xf5) [0x21b15]
  =========     Host Frame:./test_reg_memory [0x25cd]
  =========
  y = 2074
  blockDim.y = 16
  blockIdx.y = 1
  threadIdx.y = 10
```

This output does not make sense to me, because if I do the math,

```
y = blockDim.y * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y = 16 * 1 + 10 = 26 (not 2074)
```

I have spent some time looking at CUDA programming forums, and nothing has seemed to helped.  There was one thread that I read indicating that I may have corrupted register memory.  However, the one that began the thread has this problem with a different GPU.  The thread is a bit unrelated, but I included the link anyway.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/498784/memory-corruption-on-a-fermi-class-gpu-error-only-on-fermis-program-works-on-non-fermis-/?offset=6

Below I have included the nvcc version.

```
 nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
 Copyright (c) 2005-2015 NVIDIA Corporation
 Built on Tue_Aug_11_14:27:32_CDT_2015
 Cuda compilation tools, release 7.5, V7.5.17
```

Also, here is the GPU that I am using.

```
 Device 0: "GeForce GT 640"
 CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version 8.0 / 7.5
 CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number: 3.0
```

Could anyone with CUDA experience point something out that I may be doing wrong?

Comment: The code you have posted runs correctly for me and doesn't produce any errors in cuda-memcheck. Are you really certain that the code you posted gives a cuda-memcheck error if you copy-paste from the SO question, compile it and run it?

Comment: Does cudaMalloc succeed?

Comment: @RegisPortalez: If cudaMalloc failed, cuda-memcheck would report the error. The output posted contains no such error.

Comment: Your kernel will attempt to write to `data` even if `x` and/or `y` are out-of-bounds.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: While that is true, the block and grid sizes chosen should never make that occur, nor should the print statement ever print anything within the kernel (256x256 input with 16x16 blocks). But apparently it does, which I guess is the actual question. But I cannot reproduce that behaviour....

Comment: @talonmies: I am certain that the code I posted is experiencing these cuda-memcheck errors.  I actually copied and pasted my code from the question to verify.  How did you compile my code?  Also, what class of GPU are you using?  I am using a Kepler.  I am not a CUDA expert, so I am unsure if "class of GPU" is the correct terminology.

Comment: I compiled it using the same compiler version as you have for a compute 5.2 capable maxwell GPU. I also have run it under CUDA 7 with a Fermi GPU under windows. Same result. No error. I can't help you solve a problem I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @user_582: So what happened here? Have you solved this?

Comment: @talonmies: Yeah, sorry about that.  It seems like the GPU I was using was broken.  I threw my code on another GPU and it worked with no problem.

Comment: @user_582: Thanks for the update. I've taken the liberty of adding a short answer to that effect, just to get this question off the unanswered queue. If you want to edit it to add more details or change anything you are unhappy with and accept it, the question will be marked as answered.

Comment: I know question is closed, but I am curious. Did you have a look at the SASS code ? It may be that SASS code generation for your GT 240 is not correct, while it is for more recent hardware. In which case documenting this bug might be useful for others.

Answer (score 1):

This problem would appear to have been restricted to a particular system and caused by a hardware problem of some kind. The code itself was fine, and changing to a different system confirmed it worked correctly.

[This answer has been assembled from comments and added as a community wiki entry to get his question off the unanswered queue for the CUDA tag].